# Compositor for RHEL?

Tags: transparency, rhel7, window-managers, xmonad

I have Xmonad window manager installed on a RHEL 7.9 machine. The issue is I cannot seem to set the transparency for my terminal windows.

From the little previous experience I have with this, I believe I need some form of compositor.

I have tried doing a yum search for the usual suspects of compton/picom but cannot seem to find them. (This is a work machine and so I believe it has a subset of the main package repos available).

Is there any compositor like this which I should be able to use? Has anyone done this on RHEL?

If the answer is there are packages available, and I just cannot see them, I am able to request for packages to be added to our repository too, I simply need to know what they are.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This fits better on [SU] or [unix.se].

Comment: Thanks @JoachimSauer. I have posted the question over there instead. Link below in case anyone wants to follow in future.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735476/compositor-for-rhel7